# 301 redirect в htaccess помогите оочень нужно!

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите пожалуйста уже 4 часа потратил так инче и не получилось ((

Есть ссылки вида `/catalog/razdel1/razdel2` и т.д. в конце `/ID/`   `ID`- цифры, 4-5 знаков

Нужно получить по всем таким ссылкам ссылки вида `/catalog/view/ID/`. 
Но либо ни чего не работает, либо идут циклические переадресации (

пробовал так :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^catalog/view/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /catalog/view/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

и так

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/([^view]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /catalog/view/%3/%4 [R=301,L]
```

Подскажите как так сделать правильно! Спасибо!

Место в htaccess, где происходит правка

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ catalog/view/$2/$3 [R=301]
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)!view/(.*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^catalog/view$
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ /catalog/view/$2/$3 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /catalog/view/%2/%3 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Покажите пример полной ссылки http://yoursite.com?id=12&.....

Comment: yoursite.com/catalog/phones/samsung/4396/ 
либо
yoursite.com/catalog/phones/accsesuar/samsung/4396/
надо получить
yoursite.com/catalog/view/4396/
номера конечно все разные )) и ссылки после catalog/ тоже!

Comment: какой CMS стоит? и если можно старый .htaccess покозать

Comment: Битрикс конечно же ) и надо избавиться от дублей страниц, но чтобы в поиске когда люди переходили по старым ссылкам редирект был на новые
htaccess стандартный битриксовый весь смысла не вижу приводить только место где это меняем

Comment: у вас в системе уже испульзуется .htaccess вот его нужно править.

Comment: Ну это как бы понятно ) можно и внутри битрикса, там тоже правила вроде есть, вся загвоздка как правильно составить регулярное выражение что-бы все работало и небыло циклических переадресаций, если допустим было бы не catalog/ а заменить на shop/ то там все проще в разыы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сразу после

```
RewriteEngine On
```

прописываете

```
# пропускаем ссылки начинающиеся на /catalog/view
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catalog/view
# захватываем номер из ссылок вида /catalog/1иБольшеСимволовНеСлэшей/1иБольшеСимволовНеСлэшей/1иБольшеЦифра/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog/[^/]+/[^/]+/(\d+)/$
# делаем редирект на /catalog/view/ЦифрыКоторыеЗахватили/
RewriteRule . /catalog/view/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!!!
чуть подправил чтобы не только 2 вложенности учитывались))
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog/[^/]+/(.*)/(\d+)/$
то есть если кому надо будет редирект с /catalog/razd1/razd2/razd3/razd4 и тд. пока в конце не будет циферок!